# Express.js + Handlebars - trying to use regex in view

Tags: javascript, regex, express, handlebars.js

I have the following handler when accessing /articles:

```
exports.articles = (function(req, res) {
    Article.find( function(err, articles){
        if(err) {
            res.send(500, { error: err });
        }

        res.render('articles', { articles: articles });
    });
});
```

And this is the corresponding view:

```
<section id="articles">
{{#each articles}}
    <article class="geometry">
        <h4>{{ title }}</h4>
        <hr>
        <p>{{ content }}</p>
        <!-- LINK TO ARTICLE HERE -->
    </article>
{{/each}}
</section>
```

I want to build that LINK so that whenever someone clicks it, the browser should navigate to /article/title-with-dashes-instead-of-spaces. Basically, I want to use title.replace(/\s/g, '-') on the title before appending it to the  tag. Is there any way to format it like this on the view using handlebars? Or should it be done in the backend?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose it really belongs to the backend. And it's quite easy to do there:

```
Article.find( function(err, articles){
  if(err) {
    res.send(500, { error: err });
  }
  articles.forEach(function(article) {
    article.link = '/article/' + article.title.replace(/\s/g, '-');
  });
  res.render('articles', { articles: articles });
});
```

I'd rather have this code inserted into `Article` model as `generateLink()` method, as it simplifies its reusing.

An alternative is registering a Handlebars helper...

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('articleLink', function() {
  return '/article/' + this.title.replace(/\s/g, '-');
});
```

... then using it in the template:

```
<article class="geometry">
  <h4>{{ title }}</h4>
  <hr>
  <p>{{ content }}</p>
  <a href="{{ articleLink }}">Link</a>
</article>
```

Comment: Couldn't have hoped for a better answer! Thank you so much for the quick feedback!